# Direct image of structure sheaf of a singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow C$ is a degree two morphism of projective curves over complex numbers. Assume $C$ is smooth and $X$ has only nodal singularities at $d$ points and smooth elsewhere. So the images in $C$ of the $d$ points are the branch points, say $p_1,...p_d$. In this case what is $f_*O_X$? Is it $O_C\oplus O(-\Sigma\ p_i)$? Is there any restriction on $d$?

Comment: I suggest first you try the case when $X$ itself is smooth. The map still may have branch points.

Comment: @Mohan, when $X$ is smooth, we have the map $O_C\rightarrow f_*O_X$. Let the cokernel be $L$. The short exact sequence splits because of the trace map. So $f_*O_X$ is $O_C\oplus L$.

Comment: I could do the same thing when $X$ is singular as in my question I suppose. But I want to know if there is a relation between $L$ and the ramification points (or singular points in my case).

Comment: As I said, not unless you assume that the singular points are precisely the ranification locus. Apriori, all the singular points are ramified, but there could be more.

Comment: @Mohan, yes that is precisely the case. these are precisely the ramification points. Then what is L in terms of these points?